# Function in NSManagedObjectClass is failing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a `NSManagedObjectClass` Favorites. In this class I have a method `getFavoritesByArtistId` You can see it over here.

```
-(Favorites *)getFavoriteById:(int)art_id{
    Favorites *favorite;
    NSLog(@"artist is is %d",art_id);
    RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[GenkonStageDataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = store.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Favorites"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"fav_art_id == %d",art_id];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"fav_id" ascending:YES];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[descriptor];
    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    if (matches.count > 0){
        NSLog(@"till here");
        favorite = [matches objectAtIndex:0];

    }else {
        NSLog(@"till here 2");
        return  NULL;
    }

    return favorite;
}
```

In my view controller I am calling it like this.

```
  RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[GenkonStageDataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore];
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = store.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
  NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favorites" inManagedObjectContext:context];
  Favorites* favClass = [[Favorites alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
  Favorites *favorite = [favClass getFavoriteById:[artist.art_id intValue]];
```

Next I'm going to check

```
if(![favorite isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
           //Artist is already favorized !
}else{
           //Artist is not favorized !
}
```

But my app always crashes with this `CoreData _PFFastEntityRangesByType + 12, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x38)`

Any help?

Comment: Looks like you're using RestKit. Did you complete the Core Data model setup? Also, why is getFavoriteById: an instance method on Favorites?

Comment: What do you mean with Core data model setup ?

Comment: Have you called 'createManagedObjectContexts' after creating the persistent store ?